# Java generic SOAP client lib

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I wanna consume some web services, but I don't wanna use any method where eclipse or other code generation mechanism to generate any SOAP client classes for me.

I want something similar to ksoap (the one I used a loooong time ago when playing with J2ME), which enable me (freely) to create a SOAP request and parse SOAP response, without the need of using generated client codes.

I did some search on this issues in this forum too, but most are advising to use code generation method, and that is not what I'm looking for.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Bromo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I found what I'm looking for [here](https://github.com/reficio/soap-ws) in Github, and it really suit to my requirements.

Comment: FWIW: This project has been defunct since 2013. With the latest licensing driven changes to the java API (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE) it is no longer an option. IIRC this code is a thin wrapper around spring-ws, which is the developers' recommended replacement.